# Are special characters allowed in wildcard certs

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a custom wildcard cert like *xyz.domain.com.
And I have my grafana url as test-xyz.domain.com. I have enabled generic oauth in grafana.

I have enabled oauth through keycloak IDP.
When I try to login to grafana, it gives me the following error

```
t=2019-08-06T18:00:46+0000 lvl=eror msg=login.OAuthLogin(NewTransportWithCode) logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Post https://test-xyz.domain.com:31809/auth/realms/ABC/protocol/openid-connect/token: x509: certificate is valid for *xyz.domain.com, not test-xyz.domain.com"
```

Grafana fails to recognize the IDP's cert. So are special characters allowed in wildcard certs?

Comment: "custom wildcard cert like *xyz.domain.com" if this is not a typo, then this does not work. `*` can only be used as a label, so `*.xyz.example.com` or `*.example.com` but not "substring" match.

Comment: And `*` is not a special character. It is a character like any other. It has a special **meaning** (semantic) when used in specific context, like in a regexp, or in the DNS/X.509 worlds.

Comment: By special character I meant "-" in my hostname like test-xyz.

Comment: `-` is no more special than any other. `-` matches `-` and that is all. But `*xyz.domain.com` does not match anything in a certificate, since this is not allowed. See Wildcard definition and section 3.2.2.6 in https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.5.pdf